# Axios not working in React app: axios 404 error. createAxiosError (utils.js:151:1) at settle

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've had this issue with Axios. I am unsure what is the cause of it.

> axios 404 error. createAxiosError (utils.js:151:1) at settle

It happens when I make any kind of call to axios. Here is one example of it

```js
axios.get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries").then((response) => { 
  console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Any thoughts on what may be going wrong? I get the same error when running openapi generated typescript code.

thank you,

Comment: Not to get all IT helpdesk on you, but have you confirmed that axios is installed and up to date with no errors in your project?  Is it in your package.json?  And have you properly imported it into the file you're making these calls?

Comment: A 404 response should be pretty self-explanatory; the URL you're requesting is not valid. The one in your question works for me but can you get to it in your browser? What happens if you directly open https://api.publicapis.org/entries?

Comment: I thought that too, but that URL is indeed valid...

Comment: Also, use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request. Does it go to the correct URL or is it something unexpected. If the latter, I suspect you've got a badly configured [Axios interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

Comment: @PsiKai OP could have customised DNS or `hosts` file entries for `api.publicapis.org`. That's why I asked them to try opening the URL directly

Comment: Good point, sounds like you have this well in hand.

Comment: thank you guys! The link works fine when I open it manually. And I think I have it installed properly? I just did npm install --save axios or whatever the exact command is, and I checked my package.json and its in there.

I do agree that its probably an incorrectly configured axios or something. Im definitely doing something wrong.


This is the axios stuff from my package.json
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",

Comment: So what did you see in your dev-tools _Network_ panel?

Comment: So when I try to make the request, nothing happens in the network panel. It shows stuff going on when I click other buttons and when the page is loading but not when i click the button thats supposed to call axios. All i see is the error message in the console.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. For Axios to receive a 404 response, a request must have been made. If you have the dev tools open, that request must be logged in the network panel

Comment: I resolved the issue. Axios was indeed not making any requests but spitting out a 404 error. The issue had to do with a completely separate part of the code, which was not written by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else having this problem, I would recommend examining the rest of the codebase. Specifically anything that is responsible for setting up axios. I deleted the part of the codebase that was "setting up" axios and a mockup of it, and that somehow resolved the issue. I had to cut out a few parts that used this mock of axios but those parts are not necessary for my webapp.